# Turning DOM element into JavaScript class with all it's inheritances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've been searching for this for hours and found nothing.

I'm making a set of premade elements (similar to what bootstrap has) and I want all animations of these elements to be handled by jQuery and JavaScript.

All these elements have names: DFrame, DCategory, DButton and DPanel.
I've created a set of classes in javascript, along with functions such as onclick, onload, onhover etc.

Now my issue is quite simple - I want every DOM element of aforementioned classes to be turned into javascript class, so it inherits all the functions and do so executing function on an element (elem.doFunc()) will work.

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "dbutton" )[0] = new DButton();
```

For obvious reasons that resulted in: 'elem.test() is not a defined function' or something along these lines.

Thanks for any help!

@Edit:
Here's example, maybe that'll make it a bit clearer:

```
function initialize()
{
  document.getElementsByClassName( "dbutton" )[0] = new DButton();
  document.getElementsByClassName( "dbutton" )[0].test();
}
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initialize, false );

/*  
    Classes
*/

class DFrame
{

}

class DCategoryList
{

}

class DButton
{
  test()
  {
    console.log( "shows, output, etc" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have their own elements, they just add classes to the html.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: I think you might be falling victim to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). More on that [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: You're not experience a coding problem, you're experiencing a design problem. Think about what you want to do, not what you can code to accomplish that. You're asking for code as a solution to a problem, that's really only a solution for a problem that shouldn't exist. Narrow down your question. Don't think code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a stab at it by saying that dom elements aren't javascript objects. To set a dom element equal to an javascript instance is equivalent to setting my car equal to an instance of justice.

Comment: I agree - I know it wouldn't work like that because in a worst case scenario I would be replacing DOM element with a class and javascript wouldn't be able to see it as anything different.

I'm just thinking of a solution that would allow me doing so.. maybe for every element I should create a sub-element and save anything it imitates in a variable?
Like: mybutton.rep = dom element